# When i am doing ajax request with js i am getting 'Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, referrer

I am trying to send https://myownserver.com/page.php to https://myownserver.com/page2.php and I am getting: `Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade`. This is using POST request using jquery and ajax. This is my code:

```
$('.dSettings').click(function() {
    $.post('https://myownserver/page2.php', {bookid: '<?= $book['BookID']; ?>', userid: '<?= $_SESSION['Login']['UserID']; ?>', del: 'delete'}, function (data) {
        // do something with the data
    });
});
```

The problem is that i can open the page2.php from a GET request and using PostMan i can send POST request without any problems. I really don't get where the problem can be. Any help will be grateful!

EDIT: I am using Google Chrome, if someone need this information.
My Request Headers are:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:https://myownserver.com
Referer:https://myownserver.com/page.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

EDIT2: I must say that I have 2 more ajax request to the same page2.php and they are working correctly both returning: `Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade`, but also `Status Code: 200` and the one that is not working I am getting on Status Code: `(canceled)`

EDIT3: Part of my html code firing the ajax request `<a href="" class="dSettings">Do something, go somewhere</a>`

Comment: Did you forget the '.com' in the domain? Or is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: it is just a typo, sorry. i am getting the domain name from php server value so it is the right one.

Comment: add the domain in content.security.policy.default-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error, it was very stupid. **The problem was that i was using an `a` tag for when a user is clicking and then executing the ajax request, but the problem was that i have written `href=''` **an empty** href inside the a tag and that's why everything was mixing up.** Very stupid mistake i hope this will help to someone else have made the same error, but to be honest i don't believe someone else can make the same mistake, lol :D thanks all for your answers!

The fix is simple, just change it to `button` tag or inside the `a` tag just put `#` for example, but i prefer to change it with a button tag myself.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add in head section of your code

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: well that will probably will not work as i am using a class that is modifying the code when the page is send to page2.php. Then the php module Page2Module will handle the job and actually i am not displaying anything on page2 web page I am only modifying the database and after that just refreshing the page.php

Comment: You need to add this on your page.php file

Comment: yes i did, but it is not working. as my page.php is empty and actually it should not load at all, but i tried to adding it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

> This is the user agent's default behavior if no policy is specified.
>   The origin is sent as a referrer when the protocol security level
>   stays the same (HTTPS->HTTPS), but isn't sent to a less secure
>   destination (HTTPS->HTTP).

Do you use same protocols?

Comment: what kind of protocols do you mind? I am using https for both links.

Comment: btw, i have read this, but i didn't get it. i am doing https to https request.

Comment: Downgrading this reply as no full answer and solution given